# ASA5515 - QM FSM error / failed to establish L2L SA when transferring large files

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall, acl, site-to-site

I was hoping someone could help me with a problem I’m having - a little clarification or advice would be much appreciated:

The Issue: I have set a new backup server and I want to back up data from one of our production servers to the backup one. The servers are connected by a site-to-site tunnel between DC A and DC B - both using Cisco ASA 5515’s.

The way I am transferring the file is through innobackup which uses SSH (port 22). I was transferring a 5gb file when all of a sudden it got to 4.6gb and dropped the connection. I tried SCP which also uses port 22 and it did the same thing. Then I used netcat and did the transfer again on a raw port and it still failed.

So after seeing nothing in the log files and running the above tests I ruled out it was a port or ufw configuration issue, so I looked to the router for answers.  So I ran the debugging tool on the ASA and attempted the transfer again and bingo! - some logs for me!

```
FW A logs
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fbda978db0, mess id 0xd36ff5ab)!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fb9d8fde4a0, mess id 0xd36ff5ab)!

FW B logs 
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff29852230, mess id 0xd36ff5ab)!
Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA. All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= outside_map. Map Sequence Number = 1.
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff29124500, mess id 0xb09bc855)!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff29124500, mess id 0xb09bc855)!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!kbs to gb
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff29124500, mess id 0xb09bc855)!
Group = <peer ip>, IP = <peer ip>, Removing Peer from correlator table failed, no match!
```

So after looking this up on google i’ve come across two potential causes (there maybe more) - an ACL mismatch or a crypto map set security-association lifetime problem.

My Dilema - For the moment I have increased the crypto map set security-association lifetime to satisfy the size of the file transfer I require (and this works!) -  but can’t help feel this is a bit of a hack to get around another issue. You see we have another DC that contains a backup and that is using the crypto map set security-association lifetime default and transfers files of comparable sizes just fine.

The reason I haven’t gone down changing the ACL yet is because there is already one FW A and FW B under the header ‘outside_crypto_map’ in the ACL Manager - is this ignored? Or do I need to add another entry? Both ACLs are configured as follows: Source:  Destination:  Service: IP Action: Allow

Here are my sanitised configs:

FW A (MAIN):

```
ASA Version 9.8(2) 

access-list outside_cryptomap_4 extended permit ip object network_internal object Backup_Internal 

nat (inside,outside) source static network_internal network_internal destination static Backup_Internal Backup_Internal no-proxy-arp route-

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto map outside_map 7 match address outside_cryptomap_4
crypto map outside_map 7 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 7 set peer X.X.X.X
crypto map outside_map 7 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 7 set security-association lifetime kilobytes unlimited
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside


crypto isakmp identity address 
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400

 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 201
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 28800

group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 

tunnel-group X.X.X.X type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group X.X.X.X general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X
tunnel-group X.X.X.X ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key XXXXXXX
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key XXXXXXX
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key XXXXXXX
```

FW B (BACKUP):

```
    ASA Version 9.1(1) 

access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip Internal_Network object Main_DC_Internal 

nat (inside,outside) source static Internal_Network Internal_Network destination static Main_DC_Internal Main_DC_Internal no-proxy-arp route-lookup

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5-TRANS mode transport
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer X.X.X.X 
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES 3DES AES AES192 AES256
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 201
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 28800

group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 

tunnel-group X.X.X.X type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group X.X.X.X general-attributes
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_X.X.X.X
tunnel-group X.X.X.X ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key XXXXXX
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key XXXXXXXX
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key XXXXXXXX
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the (sanitized) configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Comment: OK. We'll see what one of the ASA experts has to say.

Comment: With such a huge set of phase 1 proposals and phase 2 transform sets, and the mixup with ikev1 and ikev2, this is going to be VERY difficult to troubleshoot.  (Unless this ASA serves multiple IPSec peers that still need them) I strongly suggest to remove any porposals and transform sets containing `DES, 3DES, MD5`, as these are long outdated an broken crypto standards anyway. Then you may want to remove either ikev2 or ikev1 from your crypto map, so there is no ambiguity which protocol is actually chosen. That narrows down condsiderably the set of things that might go wrong.

Comment: ... might go wrong during a Phase1 or Phase2 renegotiation. Your description that increasing lifetime parametes hides the problem is a strong hint in that direction.

Comment: Hi, yes you are correct in that FW A serves multiple peers and its a positive thing that you seem to be suggesting the same kind of problem as the guys on my Cisco community post are saying. I will conduct a review and see if I can re apply a new VPN with reduced proposal and transform sets to try and resolve this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you examine the crypto acl:s outside_cryptomap_4 in FW A and outside_cryptomap in FW B. They must be **identical but mirrored.**

The real content of the acl:s are hidden behind your usage of objects. 
Do like this:

Issue the command "show access-list outside_cryptomap_4" on FW A and "show access-list outside_cryptomap" in FW B. (Yes, show access-list, not show *run* access-list). This will show you both access-lists expanded without use of objects. They must be identical with one exception: What is source in one acl must be destination in the other and vice versa.

And yes, all acl lines must be "permit ip". No deny lines. no tcp/udp/ports and such.

If you are not familiar with running commands using SSH, you can run a specific command from ASDM using a menu entry.

Good luck!